# How to create native executable from application containing Qt and Flask

Tags: qt, flask, pyqt, pyqt4

I have a PyQt application that uses flask to expose a web server. How do I package this application for native OS deployments, for example:

exe files for windows, deb for debian based distros and similarly for osx.

Answer (score 0):

What you are looking after is a tool to **Freeze** your python application and create an executable file to be distributed to end-users so they don't need to have Python, PyQt and Flask installed on their system. There are [several solutions](http://docs.python-guide.org/en/latest/shipping/freezing/) to achieve this goal: you just need to pick up the one that suits best for you. I personally used [cx_Freeze](http://cx-freeze.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html) to freeze PyQt5 applications on *Windows*, *macOS* and *Linux* and I recommend that over other solutions.

However, for PyQt applications there is [pyqtdeploy](http://pyqt.sourceforge.net/Docs/pyqtdeploy/introduction.html), another tool to perform the freezing of the application, although I have never used it since I found it to be more complicated than other solutions (but that's just a personal thought).